# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: laravel 5 error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

i have a table employes and table contact in table employes there it a column called contactid witch is foreghn key to id in contact table when i create data in employes i gate intergrity constraints violation but i impute correct id.

here is my controller to handle create employes

```
 public function create()
{

return view('employmentform');
}

public function handleCreate(Request $request)
{




 $employe = employe::create([
            'fname' => $request->input('first_name'),
            'lname' => $request->input('last_name'),
            'phone' => $request->input('phone_number'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'houseno' => $request->input('house'),
            'kebele' => $request->input('kebele'),
            'city' => $request->input('city'),
            'state' => $request->input('state'),
            'age' => $request->input('date'),
            'username' => $request->input('user_name'),
            'sex' => $request->input('sex'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('country')),
            'salary' => $request->input('salary'),
            'bankaccount' => $request->input('account'),
            'bankname' => $request->input('bank'),
           'employedate' => getdate(),
           'contactid'=> 5,

        ]);

return Redirect::action('ContactController@create');;

}
```

i have a row with id 5 in contact table but i get error like this

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shop1`.`employes`, CONSTRAINT `employes_contactid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`contactid`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `employes` (`fname`, `lname`, `phone`, `email`, `houseno`, `kebele`, `city`, `state`, `age`, `username`, `sex`, `password`, `salary`, `bankaccount`, `bankname`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (eu, tseu, 0912378909, eualtse@gmail.com, hdikw, sdo, sjad, jaos, 2007-09-09, euael, Female, y$VhU2iJSuXAoXqsan38Gsve5JGtahhNeYpzeJjAYRnTGAEI1TeBCaK, 3000, 9839408, enb, 2015-05-16 13:07:09, 2015-05-16 13:07:09))
```

my table schema

```
Schema::table('employes', function($table)
{
   $table->integer('contactid')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('contactid')->references('id')->on('contacts'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are entering value 5 for contactid which is a froeign key in your employees table and primary key in contact table as id. Now you are entering a constant value into employee table irrespective of the fact whether you have id 5 in contact table or not. By looking at the error it is clear that you do not have an entry in contact table where id is 5.

Comment: i have a row with id 5 in contact table

Comment: Schema::table('employes', function($table)
{
    $table->integer('contactid')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('contactid')->references('id')->on('contacts');
});